# Is it possible to save files to resource folder using javascript on iPhone app?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I am new to iPhone app development and I just got a idea of making a great and fancy app in an easy way, using Javascript and UIWebview. My question is that, is it possible to have local HTML/Javascript files inside the resource folder? If so, can I edit/delete/add files to resource folder with Javascript language? Because I'm planning to make a app with settings with on and off. Basically, what I'm planning to do is open a file and update the information with Javascript. So the next time the client open the same app (for example after restarting his iPhone) the settings will be the same as before the restart.

Answer (score 1):

Making an app using javascript and a `UIWebView` is a bad idea. An app made that way will be neither great or fancy.

Not that it's relevant, but I don't think what you're asking for is possible, so you can't do it even if you'd want to. Learn iPhone programming. It's worth it.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily agree with it being a bad idea, but I agree with everything else....

Answer (score 1):

Not using pure Javascript, no, but check out frameworks like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com).

Comment: I've downloaded a few apps that use PhoneGap and there's nothing great and fancy about them. Sure it's nice that your app will run on all major platforms, but they really don't compare to native apps.

Comment: I can promise you that it is possible to create powerful applications with JavaScript but no one has done it yet on phonegap.